# Selecting just "th" from "11th March" using regex

Tags: php, regex, sublimetext2

How can I replace th, nd, st from the following data using regex with anything say a space.

my random text goes here with th in it..... "11th March" ....my random text goes here with th in it.
my random text goes here with nd in it..... "02nd March" ....my random text goes here with nd in it.
my random text goes here with st in it..... "01st March" ....my random text goes here with st in it.

So far I tried this [0-9]0-9 but it also replaces the number. How do I retain digits or just select those required parts?

Comment: [Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)

Comment: I am using sublime text 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=\d)(th|rd|nd|st)`

[Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: A bit terse as an answer, but correct. Can you show how the "replace" part would work?

Comment: @Floris I am using the Sublime Text 2's search and replace feature for now. If I would like to do the same in PHP how would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the number characters and match the following `th`, `nd`, `st`.

Usually a back-reference is either `$1` or `\1` for the first match of a pattern in parentheses.

Try the following:

```
Find: ([0-9]+)[a-zA-Z]{2}
Replace: $1
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/hJ4iV4)

Answer (score 1):

In php, the following code snippet works to do the find-and-replace of `st`, `nd`, etc immediately after a digit, and replacing it with `**`. You can see where you can insert "any string" for replacement.

With a big tip of the hat to @jaco0646 !

```
<?php
$inputString = 'This is the 2nd of November<br>';
$pattern = '/(?<=[0-9])(st|nd|rd|th)/';
$replacement = '**';

$newString = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $inputString);
echo $inputString;
echo $newString;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the PHP version.

Comment: I added this in response to your comment "If I could like to do the same in PHP…" - I thought @jaco0464's answer was a little too light on details.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=\"\d+)[a-zA-Z]+
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

As Johnsyweb suggests, the exact syntax of the replace command will depend on what language you are using.
jaco0646 has a good regex for matching what you want, and, critically, captures it. (The second set of parentheses does that (as well as grouping the alternatives). The first set of parentheses is non-capturing, by the way, thanks to the `?` as the first character within them.)
Anyway, having captured the text you want, you will refer to that capture group in your replacement expression as `\1`. That's backslash-one.
If you had multiple capturing groups in your regex, then you could refer to the second one with `\2`, and so on.
If you have nested capturing groups, then you count them in the order of their opening parenthesis. So in `((foo)bar)`, for example, `\1`would be "foobar" and `\2` would just be "foo".